# Welcome file not working with html file in spring

Tags: html, spring, jsp, maven, welcome-file

I have given my welcome file in web.xml
But when running the application, it is showing 404 error on `http://172.16.2.16:8080/sampletest/`

It is a spring application.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>sampletest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using eclipse luna, java 8, tomcat 8 and maven framework.
index.html file is directly under webapp folder and web.xml is under webapp/WEB-INF folder.
**If I use index.jsp instead of index.html, it is working. Then welcome page will load using `http://172.16.2.16:8080/sampletest/`**

The issue is only with welcome file. Otherwise spring configuration is working.
`http://localhost:8080/sampletest/test/` will load the data from database.

**Error log in console**

......................

```
Jul 10, 2014 12:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4963 ms
Jul 10, 2014 12:38:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sampletest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Dispatcher**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.test" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.sample.test.domain</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampletest?autoConnect=true" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- HibernateTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="flushModeName">
            <value>FLUSH_AUTO</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.sample.test.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.sample.test.dto.Response;
import com.sample.test.facade.AccelFlowFacade;

@Controller
public class SampleTestController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sampleTestFacade")
    SampleTestFacade sampleTestFacade;

    public SampleTestFacade getSampleTestFacade() {
        return sampleTestFacade;
    }

    public void setSampleTestFacade(SampleTestFacade sampleTestFacade) {
        this.sampleTestFacade= sampleTestFacade;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Response display() throws Exception {
        sampleTestFacade.disaply();
        Response res = new Response();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` try to have your web.xml to have this

Comment: can you post your web.xml?

Comment: can you post ur project structure's snap...

Comment: `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>` try to remove this

Comment: @Niang he wants to load the welcome file for the default url

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` in your dispatcher-servlet.xml.

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) for details.

Comment: I tried yesterday it. but did not worked. So what I did is, set <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> in dispatcher-servelet.xml. And modified the url pattern in web.xml file as <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>

Comment: You do not have to change the url pattern. `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` with `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` should work.

Comment: Just in case, `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` and `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` are completely different.

Answer (score 6):

You have mapped all your incoming requests to the `dispatcher` here,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So all your `URL` requests for the application goes inside the dispatcher  as '/' maps all incoming requests . check for the stacktraces in your application server log

**update:**

You get the below warning because there are no handler for the '/' pattern,

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AccelFlow/] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

You can do either of below options ,

1. Map a url with '/' to the controller
2. Add a specific URL pattern to the spring dispatcher such as `.htm or .do` as you wish

Modify your **web.xml**,

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And in your controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Response display() throws Exception {
    accelFlowFacade.disaply();
    Response res = new Response();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At the startup by default  all incoming requests are mapping to '/' pattern as you write in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**update:**

1. Try to map a Controller method for the default view:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
   public String welcome() {
       return "index";
   }
   ```
2. Add viewresolver to dispather-servlet.xml:

   ```
   <bean id="viewResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
         p:prefix="/"
         p:suffix=".jsp" />
   ```
3. Remove welcome file from the web.xml as automatically spring will search for index page by default:

   ```
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome file can be access using following changes.

change 1. add resource path in dispatcher as following :

```
      <mvc:resources mapping="/" location="/index.html" />
```

change 2. add controller handler like following :

```
     @Controller
      public class RestController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String welcome() {
            return "index.html";
      }

     }
```

changes 3: index.html file should be in WebContent folder in project.

Note : If you are not able to add mvc bean in dispatcher servlet file then add

```
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
```

in dispatcher servlet config file.

Answer (score 0):

using `<mvc:resources mapping="/" location="/index.html" />` is goods for static pages , however changing it to

`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String welcome() {
            return "index.html";
      }`

is not good design as all model in other controllers  may point back to index page, instead use

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/" location="/redfresh.html"  />
```

and make refresh page such

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/index'" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and point in controller to index such:

```
@Controller
public class indexPageController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String index() {       
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your index.html to webContent folder. Because welcome file is searched in that folder itself.